# How to disable the default CAPTCHA packaged with Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, default, captcha

I've recently stumbled into an error using the default version of CAPTCHA in Magento 1.9: `"Image CAPTCHA requires FT fonts support"`.

As far as my understanding goes, this means FreeType font support isn't enabled on the server. As this version of reCAPTCHA is old, I don't see any reason to resolve this issue, and have opted for [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/recaptcha-1.html) extension, which uses version 2 and I have no issues.

The problem is that, if a client enables the built-in CAPTCHA in `CUSTOMERS > Customer Configuration > CAPTCHA > Enable CAPTCHA on Frontend > Yes` or `Advanced > Admin > CAPTCHA > Enabled CAPTCHA in Admin > Yes`, any page this is enabled for will crash that specific page.

So whilst it is avoidable by not fiddling with settings, this is not desirable and will likely be confused with the proprietary extension.

What would be the best way to remove this from Magento?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that the custom extension does not extend `Mage_Captcha` and instead uses their own implementation, you can disable the core module entirely. Create a file `app/etc/modules/Zzz_Deactivate.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mage_Captcha>
      <active>false</active>
    </Mage_Captcha>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Given the existing `Mage_Captcha.xml` that already exists, is there any important reason for your `Zzz` prefix? E.g. are you intending this be loaded after `Mage_Captcha.xml` or is this just a way to safely namespace it (assuming uniqueness)?

Comment: Never touch the core. This makes sure that an update won't activate it again. The files in `app/etc/modules` are loaded alphabetically, so to disable core or third party modules, I usually use a file like this to make sure it overrides all others.

Comment: Yep. I am aware never to touch the core. I am just wondering the reasoning behind your prefix. I see, thanks for this extra info.

Comment: The `.xml` files are applied in alphabetical order so anything starting with `Zzz_` will be last man standing and its contents will overwrite any xml node in any of the previous parsed `.xml` files when Magento assembles its XML configuration list.

Answer (score 0):

If a captcha from third-party developers, then you can find it in the table core_config_data by searching through LIKE%...% by the word captcha. Where the value is not 0, but 1, there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sir/Madam:

I always get the CAPTCHA as invalid. I cleared the cookies and cache using the Chrome browser. I still get the same difficulty. I am now asked 'to disable the default Magento or Third Party Captcha'. I do not know how to do it. I request your step by step guidance since I am not an expert in PC systems. If you can kindly help me in not getting the CAPTCHA to be invalid, I shall be extremely grateful. Thank you. My name is M.A.Velsuwami.

Comment: Waiting for your kind help in solving my problem 'how to solve Captcha to be always valid'